# C#, ListView icons appear one on another

Tags: c#

For same strange reason icons in different groups of my listview appear on top of one another... any ideas what might be causing it?

[image]

Thanks!

edit:
no, originally the view was set to SmallIcons. When I try setting it to Details, it looks perfect, only the names get cut short. :)

[image]

Comment: please provide more information and some code so we can try to help you figure this out.

Comment: There are several reasons to cause it, maybe properties or code, either the way show the part of your code where you construct it, may help us help you

Comment: there isn't anything coded yet, just manually added a listview, two groups and some items into them.

Comment: What properties do you think might be responsible for it?

Comment: FOUND IT, JUST HAD TO SET THE COLUMN WIDTH LARGER. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being forced to guess with no repro steps whatsoever, I'd say you used View = Tile and made the TileSize property value too small.  If that's not it, copy and paste the content of InitializeComponent() from the form's Designer.cs file into your post.

Comment: no, originally the view was set to SmallIcons. When I try setting it to Details, it looks perfect, only the names get cut short. :)

Comment: You are wasting everybody's time by refusing to post the code in InitializeComponent().  Voting to close.

Comment: can't find it :( in which InitializeComponent should be this listview? as I just dragged it into the form, not initialized it by code.

Comment: FOUND IT, JUST HAD TO SET THE COLUMN WIDTH LARGER. :)